# UK visit visa. Travelling together, one applicant uses priority service. What are the effects?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My family and I applied for a visit visa to travel to the UK together. Because of his job, my dad used the priority service and the rest of us used the standard one. Is there any chance our applications don’t link together as my dad’s application will be decided first? Would this delay the decision for the other family members?

My worry is they don’t get linked together as the important evidences are all on my dad’s application (the primary).

Comment: Even if you all used the same service, it is possible that some can be approved and others refused.

Comment: @user16259 yes I’m aware that decision is based upon individual circumstances. My question is regarding the technical process.

Comment: @Rosesandteacups Did you cross reference the applications by including all the related reference numbers in each one?

Comment: @Traveller yes I did. Father also have a financial support letter with our names, passports, and reference numbers because he half funds the trip. Would this help?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no delay for the other application as I got mine and the others exactly on the 15th day. This applies for straightforward case where there is no previous refusal. To be extra sure, just cross reference each applicant GWF numbers.

Keep in mind, the decision is based upon each applicant's circumstances, not just because the primary got the visa first.